# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. in IIS 7 (web service project)

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

> error in sending: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified.

I get the exception above when I deploy my web service into IIS7, and call the web service from the browser.

It works well in Visual Studio 2008, I can call the web service in client.

I researched on Google, and found that it might be the permission issue, as in my web service I will call a COM API, which is encapsulated into a DLL.

My question is why when I run it in Visual Studio, it works well but fails in IIS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so, have you checked the permissions?

Remember that Visual Studio is not running as the same user as IIS. That means that if `IUSR` user does not have a permission to access a file, you will still be able to access it when running your website from Visual Studio.

Comment: I am sure that I set permission to the whole folder of whole website